# Example of SAF client in Play Store

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, storage-access-framework

I'm looking for a client application of Android's Storage Access Framework in Google Play; a free app please. Something that allows you to both store files and open files from a documents provider. This could be a simple text editor that allows saving the file into SAF and then using the SAF picker to load a file.

I'm developing my own documents provider and I usually use my own test client when demoing it to others. When I say that other apps on the market using SAF are able to use my provider the obvious question is "can I see an example". Problem is I haven't been able to find concrete examples of SAF clients. There is MS Word but it only allows opening files, not saving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with [QuickEdit Text Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.edit).

It's free and it supports both read and write from Android's Storage Access Framework.

Comment: Using regular file system we can both read and write. As far as using SAF is concerned, it only supports opening the file, not saving it afterwards.

Comment: Strange, I tried with Google Drive, it reads and saves a text file without any problem. To save the document you need to press the first icon in the action bar, then press Save. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I was trying to write on a new document and saving it using SAF but all I was getting was the file system browser. However, if I open an existing file using SAF, it is possible to edit it and save it afterwards. So you're correct, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately QuckEdit 0.9.3 does not support a NEW document creation.